# WCF Restful endpoint configuration to pass multiple values

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have created a WCF restful service that returns group information in xml format that is basically a string. To get this information I need to pass two parameters like PersonId and GroupId - both are string. Here a person can have more than one groups. The logic is if I pass both - PersonId and GroupId then it will return the specific information of that group only, but if I do not pass the GroupId then method will return all the groups of that person. Up to now I was using this service via get method, for example

```
localhost/service/service.svc/getGroupInfo?PersonId=A100&GroupId=E100

or 

localhost/service/service.svc/getGroupInfo?PersonId=A100&GroupId=
```

The interface is like below :

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
string getGroupInfo(string PersonId, string GroupId);
```

and it was giving me accurate result what I was expected. Then I tried to make it RESTFull and added `UriTemplate` attribute in the `webInvoke`. For example

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,UriTemplate = "getGroupInfo/{PersonId}/{GroupId}")]
    string getGroupInfo(string PersonId, string GroupId);
```

To make my service RESTfull like

```
localhost/service/service.svc/getGroupInfo/A100/E100
```

And it is working fine.
But now my problem has started. If I do not set the GroupId, it gives service not found or bad request error. I want to set groupId optionally. 
For example

For single group

```
localhost/service/service.svc/getGroupInfo/A100/E100
```

and for all groups

```
localhost/service/service.svc/getGroupInfo/A100
```

Is it possible?

Awaiting for your valuable response..

Thank you..

Comment: For all formats check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675245.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could change your template to be "getGroupInfo/{PersonId}/{GroupId=null}" but I believe you'd still need a trailing backslash in your URL when querying all groups

```
localhost/service/service.svc/getGroupInfo/A100/
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create 2 methods:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,UriTemplate = "getGroupInfo/{PersonId}")]
string getGroupInfo(string PersonId)
{
    return getGroupInfo(PersonId, null);
}

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,UriTemplate = "getGroupInfo/{PersonId}/{GroupId}")]
string getGroupInfo(string PersonId, string GroupId)
{
}
```

To use optional parameters you'll have to use a '?'

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,UriTemplate = "getGroupInfo/{PersonId}?GroupId={GroupId}")]
string getGroupInfo(string PersonId, string GroupId)
{
}
```